# How to safely multi-thread in a PySide6/PyQt app?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside6, connect-four

This is a *Python* implementation of the *AlphaZero* Algorithm for the *Connect-Four* game using *PySide6*. Since this is a GUI-focused implementation, I have added a graphical timer to time the players. Everything is working great, except the AI logic computation is taking a significant amount of time to complete. The problem is that *AlphaZero* logic blocks the main *Qt* event loop and the timer freezes. I tried to separate the AI logic from the main class using `QThread` class and used signals and slots for communication, but the problem persists. What did I miss?
Another approach that I was wondering about was *Python*'s multithreading library, but *ChatGPT* dismissed that option.
Here is the full code and the [link to the trained *AlphaZero*
*PyTorch* model](https://github.com/foersterrobert/AlphaZeroFromScratch/blob/main/model_7_ConnectFour.pt). The worker Thread is implemented in `AlphaZeroWorker(QThread)` class, with it being instantiated in  `MainWindow(QMainWindow)`, which is the parent class to the three child classes `Connect4Board(QWidget)`, `TimerWidget(QWidget)` and `GameInfoWidget(QWidget)`. You may safely ignore the first four classes, namely `Node`, `MCTS`, `ResBlock` and `ResNet`.
You can run the code as it is and play the game after setting the below variable

```py
# Don't forget to set the 'path_to_AI_model' variable to the path to the downloaded trained-model
path_to_AI_model = 

import sys
import random
from enum import Enum
import functools
from PySide6.QtCore import QTimer, Qt, Signal, QRect, QThread, Slot
from PySide6.QtGui import QPainter, QColor, QPen, QFont, QBrush
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, QMainWindow, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QSizePolicy, QGridLayout, QLayout
import numpy as np
print(np.__version__)
import torch
print(torch.__version__)
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
torch.manual_seed(0)
from tqdm.notebook import trange
import random
import math

class CurrentPlayer(Enum):
    HUMAN = 1
    COMPUTER = -1

class gameStatus(Enum):
    HUMAN_LOST = -1
    DRAW = 0
    HUMAN_WON = 1
    IN_PROGRESS = 2

class Node:
    def __init__(self, game, args, state, parent=None, action_taken=None, prior=0, visit_count=0):
        self.game = game
        self.args = args
        self.state = state
        self.parent = parent
        self.action_taken = action_taken
        self.prior = prior
        
        self.children = []
        
        self.visit_count = visit_count
        self.value_sum = 0
        
    def is_fully_expanded(self):
        return len(self.children) > 0
    
    def select(self):
        best_child = None
        best_ucb = -np.inf
        
        for child in self.children:
            ucb = self.get_ucb(child)
            if ucb > best_ucb:
                best_child = child
                best_ucb = ucb
                
        return best_child
    
    def get_ucb(self, child):
        if child.visit_count == 0:
            q_value = 0
        else:
            q_value = 1 - ((child.value_sum / child.visit_count) + 1) / 2
        return q_value + self.args['C'] * (math.sqrt(self.visit_count) / (child.visit_count + 1)) * child.prior
    
    def expand(self, policy):
        for action, prob in enumerate(policy):
            if prob > 0:
                child_state = self.state.copy()
                child_state = self.game.get_next_state(child_state, action, 1)
                child_state = self.game.change_perspective(child_state, player=-1)

                child = Node(self.game, self.args, child_state, self, action, prob)
                self.children.append(child)
                
        return child
            
    def backpropagate(self, value):
        self.value_sum += value
        self.visit_count += 1
        
        value = self.game.get_opponent_value(value)
        if self.parent is not None:
            self.parent.backpropagate(value)  

class MCTS:
    def __init__(self, game, args, model):
        self.game = game
        self.args = args
        self.model = model
        
    @torch.no_grad()
    def search(self, state):
        root = Node(self.game, self.args, state, visit_count=1)
        
        policy, _ = self.model(
            torch.tensor(self.game.get_encoded_state(state), device=self.model.device).unsqueeze(0)
        )
        policy = torch.softmax(policy, axis=1).squeeze(0).cpu().numpy()
        policy = (1 - self.args['dirichlet_epsilon']) * policy + self.args['dirichlet_epsilon'] \
            * np.random.dirichlet([self.args['dirichlet_alpha']] * self.game.action_size)
        
        valid_moves = self.game.get_valid_moves(state)
        policy *= valid_moves
        policy /= np.sum(policy)
        root.expand(policy)
        
        for search in range(self.args['num_searches']):
            node = root
            
            while node.is_fully_expanded():
                node = node.select()
                
            value, is_terminal = self.game.get_value_and_terminated(node.state, node.action_taken)
            value = self.game.get_opponent_value(value)
            
            if not is_terminal:
                policy, value = self.model(
                    torch.tensor(self.game.get_encoded_state(node.state), device=self.model.device).unsqueeze(0)
                )
                policy = torch.softmax(policy, axis=1).squeeze(0).cpu().numpy()
                valid_moves = self.game.get_valid_moves(node.state)
                policy *= valid_moves
                policy /= np.sum(policy)
                
                value = value.item()
                
                node.expand(policy)
                
            node.backpropagate(value)    
            
            
        action_probs = np.zeros(self.game.action_size)
        for child in root.children:
            action_probs[child.action_taken] = child.visit_count
        action_probs /= np.sum(action_probs)
        return action_probs
    
class ResBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_hidden):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(num_hidden, num_hidden, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(num_hidden)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(num_hidden, num_hidden, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(num_hidden)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        residual = x
        x = F.relu(self.bn1(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.bn2(self.conv2(x))
        x += residual
        x = F.relu(x)
        return x
    
class ResNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, game, num_resBlocks, num_hidden, device):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.device = device
        self.startBlock = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(3, num_hidden, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(num_hidden),
            nn.ReLU()
        )
        
        self.backBone = nn.ModuleList(
            [ResBlock(num_hidden) for i in range(num_resBlocks)]
        )
        
        self.policyHead = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(num_hidden, 32, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Flatten(),
            nn.Linear(32 * game.row_count * game.column_count, game.action_size)
        )
        
        self.valueHead = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(num_hidden, 3, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(3),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Flatten(),
            nn.Linear(3 * game.row_count * game.column_count, 1),
            nn.Tanh()
        )
        
        self.to(device)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.startBlock(x)
        for resBlock in self.backBone:
            x = resBlock(x)
        policy = self.policyHead(x)
        value = self.valueHead(x)
        return policy, value
    
class ConnectFour:
    def __init__(self):
        self.row_count = 6
        self.column_count = 7
        self.action_size = self.column_count
        self.in_a_row = 4
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return "ConnectFour"
        
    def get_initial_state(self):
        return np.zeros((self.row_count, self.column_count))
    
    def get_next_state(self, state, action, player):
        row = np.max(np.where(state[:, action] == 0))
        state[row, action] = player
        return state
    
    def get_valid_moves(self, state):
        return (state[0] == 0).astype(np.uint8)
    
    def check_win(self, state, action):
        if action == None:
            return False
        
        row = np.min(np.where(state[:, action] != 0))
        column = action
        player = state[row][column]

        def count(offset_row, offset_column):
            for i in range(1, self.in_a_row):
                r = row + offset_row * i
                c = action + offset_column * i
                if (
                    r < 0 
                    or r >= self.row_count
                    or c < 0 
                    or c >= self.column_count
                    or state[r][c] != player
                ):
                    return i - 1
            return self.in_a_row - 1

        return (
            count(1, 0) >= self.in_a_row - 1 # vertical
            or (count(0, 1) + count(0, -1)) >= self.in_a_row - 1 # horizontal
            or (count(1, 1) + count(-1, -1)) >= self.in_a_row - 1 # top left diagonal
            or (count(1, -1) + count(-1, 1)) >= self.in_a_row - 1 # top right diagonal
        )
    
    def get_value_and_terminated(self, state, action):
        if self.check_win(state, action):
            return 1, True
        if np.sum(self.get_valid_moves(state)) == 0:
            return 0, True
        return 0, False
    
    def get_opponent(self, player):
        return -player
    
    def get_opponent_value(self, value):
        return -value
    
    def change_perspective(self, state, player):
        return state * player
    
    def get_encoded_state(self, state):
        encoded_state = np.stack(
            (state == -1, state == 0, state == 1)
        ).astype(np.float32)
        
        return encoded_state
    
class AlphaZeroWorker(QThread):
    dataToMain = Signal(dict)

    def __init__(self, mainWindow):
        super().__init__()
        mainWindow.dataToWorker.connect(self.computeNextMove)
        self.device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
        self.game = ConnectFour()
        self.args = {
            'C': 2,
            'num_searches': 1000,
            'dirichlet_epsilon': 0.,
            'dirichlet_alpha': 0.3
        }
        self.model = ResNet(self.game, 9, 128, self.device)
        self.model.load_state_dict(torch.load(path_to_AI_model, map_location=self.device))
        self.model.eval()
        self.mcts = MCTS(self.game, self.args, self.model)
    
    def computeNextMove(self, data):
        moves = data["moves"]
        player = data["player"]
        action = data["action"]

        neutral_state = self.game.change_perspective(moves, player)
        mcts_probs = self.mcts.search(neutral_state)
        action = np.argmax(mcts_probs)
        moves = self.game.get_next_state(moves, action, player)
        val, is_terminal = self.game.get_value_and_terminated(moves, action)
        return_dict = {"moves": moves, "val": val, "is_terminal": is_terminal}
        self.dataToMain.emit(return_dict)


class TimerWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent, cellWidth):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent().buttonClickedSignal.connect(self.resetTimer)
        self.parent().timerResetSignal.connect(self.resetTimer)
        self.parent().gameOverSignal.connect(self.resetTimer)
        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.cellWidth = cellWidth
        self.time_elapsed = 0
        self.max_time = 20000
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updateTimer)
        self.timer.start(20)

    def updateTimer(self):
        self.time_elapsed += 20
        if self.time_elapsed >= self.max_time:
            self.timer.stop()
            self.parent().status = gameStatus.HUMAN_LOST
            self.parent().gameOverSignal.emit()
            self.parent().update()
        self.update()
    
    def resetTimer(self):
        self.time_elapsed = 0
        if self.parent().status != gameStatus.IN_PROGRESS:
            self.timer.stop()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter(self)
        if not qp.isActive():
            qp.begin(self)
        qp.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        qp.fillRect(self.rect(), QBrush(QColor(20, 20, 20)))
        rect = self.rect()
        w = min(rect.width(), rect.height()) - self.cellWidth
        rect = QRect(self.cellWidth/2, self.cellWidth/2, w, w)
        start_angle = 90 * 16 
        span_angle = abs(int((self.max_time - self.time_elapsed) / self.max_time * 360 * 16))
        pen = QPen()
        pen.setColor(QColor(255, 255, 255))
        pen.setWidth(10)
        qp.setPen(pen)
        qp.drawEllipse(rect)
        if self.parent().player == CurrentPlayer.COMPUTER:
            pen.setColor(QColor(50, 255, 0))
        else:
            pen.setColor(QColor(50, 0, 255))
        pen.setWidth(11)
        qp.setPen(pen)
        qp.drawArc(rect, start_angle, span_angle)
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        qp.setFont(font)
        time_left_in_seconds = int(abs(self.max_time - self.time_elapsed)/1000)
        qp.drawText(rect, Qt.AlignCenter, f"Time Left:\n{time_left_in_seconds} seconds")
        qp.end()
        
class gameInfoWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.statusMessageDict = {
            -1: "Game Over\nYou Lost",
            0: "Game Over\nDraw",
            1: "Game Over\nYou Won!",
            2: "Game in Progress",
        }

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter(self)
        if not qp.isActive():
            qp.begin(self)
        pen = QPen()
        font = QFont()
        pen.setColor(QColor(255, 255, 255))
        font.setPointSize(15)
        qp.setPen(pen)
        qp.setFont(font)
        message = self.statusMessageDict.get(self.parent().status.value, "Unknown Status")
        qp.drawText(self.rect(), Qt.AlignCenter, message)
        self.show()
        qp.end()

class Connect4Board(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent, cellWidth):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.cellWidth = cellWidth
        self.buttons = []
        self.action1 = 0
        self.button_i_status = [True for _ in range(7)]
        self.moves = np.array([[0 for _ in range(7)] for _ in range(6)])
        self.parent().gameOverSignal.connect(self.disableButtons)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(self.rect())
        self.createButtons()
        self.show()

    def createButtons(self):
        font = QFont("Arial", 15) 
        for column in range(7):
            self.buttons.append(QPushButton(f"{column+1}", self))
            self.buttons[column].setFont(font)
            self.buttons[column].setGeometry((column+0.75)*self.cellWidth, 6.75*self.cellWidth, self.cellWidth/2, self.cellWidth/2)
            self.buttons[column].clicked.connect(functools.partial(self.buttonClicked, column))

    def disableButtons(self):
        for column in range(0, 7):
            self.buttons[column].setEnabled(False)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter(self)
        if not qp.isActive():
            qp.begin(self)
        qp.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.drawBackground(qp)
        self.drawGrid(qp)
        self.drawMoves(qp)
        qp.end()

    def drawBackground(self, qp):
        qp.fillRect(self.rect(), QBrush(QColor(20, 20, 20)))
        
    def drawGrid(self, qp):
        qp.setPen(Qt.white)
        qp.setBrush(Qt.white)
        for i in range(0, 7):
           qp.drawLine(self.cellWidth/2, (i+0.5)*self.cellWidth, 7.5*self.cellWidth, (i+0.5)*self.cellWidth)
        for i in range(0, 8):
           qp.drawLine((i+0.5)*self.cellWidth, self.cellWidth/2, (i+0.5)*self.cellWidth, 6.5*self.cellWidth)

    def drawMoves(self, qp):
        for i in range(0, 6):
            for j in range(0, 7):
                if self.moves[i][j]:
                    if self.moves[i][j] == CurrentPlayer.COMPUTER.value:
                        qp.setPen(QColor(50, 255, 0))
                        qp.setBrush(QColor(50, 255, 0))
                    else:
                        qp.setPen(QColor(50, 0, 255))
                        qp.setBrush(QColor(50, 0, 255))
                    qp.drawEllipse((j+0.6)*self.cellWidth, (i+0.6)*self.cellWidth, 0.8*self.cellWidth, 0.8*self.cellWidth)
            
    def buttonClicked(self, column):
        if self.moves[0][column] == 0:
            for row in range(-1, -7, -1):
                if self.moves[row][column] == 0:
                    self.moves[row][column] = self.parent().player.value
                    break
            self.parent().repaint()
            for column in range(7):
                self.buttons[column].setEnabled(False)
            self.parent().buttonClickedSignal.emit()
            self.parent().switchPlayer()
            dataDict = {"moves":self.moves, "player":self.parent().player.value, "action":column}
            self.parent().dataToWorker.emit(dataDict)
        else:
            self.button_i_status[column] = False

    def computerMove(self, data):
        self.moves = data["moves"]
        val = data["val"]
        is_terminal = data["is_terminal"]
        if is_terminal:
            print(self.moves)
            if val == 1:
                print(self.parent().player, "won")
                if self.parent().player.value == 1:
                    self.parent().status = self.parent().status.HUMAN_WON
                elif self.parent().player.value == -1:
                    self.parent().status = self.parent().status.HUMAN_LOST
            else:
                self.parent().status = gameStatus.DRAW
                print("draw")
            self.parent().gameOverSignal.emit()
            self.parent().update()
        else:
            self.parent().update()
            self.parent().switchPlayer()
            self.parent().timerResetSignal.emit()
            for column in range(7):
                if self.button_i_status[column]:
                    self.buttons[column].setEnabled(True)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    buttonClickedSignal = Signal()
    timerResetSignal = Signal()
    gameOverSignal = Signal()
    dataToWorker = Signal(dict)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.player = CurrentPlayer.HUMAN
        self.status = gameStatus.IN_PROGRESS
        self.cellWidth = 80
        self.moveCount = 1
        self.alphazero = AlphaZeroWorker(self)
        self.alphazero.moveToThread(self.alphazero.thread())
        self.board = Connect4Board(self, self.cellWidth)
        self.timer = TimerWidget(self, self.cellWidth)
        self.gameInfo = gameInfoWidget(self)
        self.alphazero.dataToMain.connect(self.board.computerMove)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Connect Four")
        self.setFixedSize(10.5*self.cellWidth, 7.5*self.cellWidth)

        self.board.setGeometry(0, 0, 7.5*self.cellWidth, 7.5*self.cellWidth)
        self.timer.setGeometry(7.5*self.cellWidth, 0, 3*self.cellWidth, 3*self.cellWidth)
        self.gameInfo.setGeometry(7.5*self.cellWidth, 3.5*self.cellWidth, 3*self.cellWidth, 5*self.cellWidth)

        self.board.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.timer.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gameInfo.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)

        self.board.setMinimumSize(7.5*self.cellWidth, 7.5*self.cellWidth)
        self.timer.setMinimumSize(3*self.cellWidth, 3*self.cellWidth)
        self.gameInfo.setMinimumSize(3*self.cellWidth, 5*self.cellWidth)

        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter(self)
        if not qp.isActive():
            qp.begin(self)
        qp.fillRect(self.rect(), QBrush(QColor(20, 20, 20)))
        qp.end()

    def switchPlayer(self):
        if self.player == CurrentPlayer.COMPUTER:
            self.player = CurrentPlayer.HUMAN
        else:
            self.player = CurrentPlayer.COMPUTER

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if QApplication.instance():
        app = QApplication.instance()
    else:
        app = QApplication([])
    player = CurrentPlayer.HUMAN
    gameMainWindow = MainWindow()
    app.exec()
    app.quit()
    del app
```

One more thing: please tell me how to arrange widgets using QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout or QGridLayout so that they are effectively arranged as they are now. I tried all of those ways but ended up with widgets being placed on top of each other. Thank You!

Comment: Sorry but your code is too extended and StackOverflow is not really a debugging service nor a code provider. Please provide a valid [mre]. Also, only one question can be asked in each post, so if you have issues with your layout consider creating a separate question, but be aware that QMainWindow has its own internal layout, which is used to manage toolbars and other objects, so, as the [documentation explains](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmainwindow.html), you *must* set a central widget, which will eventually have its own layout set.

Comment: Another important point you should really be aware of: current generative AI models are not capable of deep understanding of logical context, and they're known for having [*hallucinations*](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hallucination_(artificial_intelligence) (they often make mistakes even with simple math questions), so you should really not rely on answers from ChatGPT or similar tools, because: 1. it surely didn't really *understand* the problem; 2. its responses are not reliable. That's one of the reasons for which content created from AI is [banned on SO](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831).

Comment: @musicamante I could explain the code, if necessary. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but no, you don't have to "explain the code", nor we need to ask further clarifications in its current state: it's just too extended, and, as already said, SO is not a debugging service. Questions should always be self-contained (so, they shall never rely on external services, especially if they are repositories that could change their contents and make the question invalid) and provide a code that is *both* minimal *and* easily reproducible. We must be able to focus on the actual problem, not distracted by trying to reproduce it or even understanding where the problem is.

Comment: @musicamante there is really no bug, at all. The code does the job. I am asking for an improvement. If I post a minimalist version of my code, where would I put the full code for the potential answer-givers to check-out? Further, I have mentioned what classes to ignore and what to consider. But you are correct in that a working code explains itself. My intention is that when one sees the code in action, then a naturally arising question would be "how did he do that"? It is just a simple implementation of a simple game. One can consider it to be a minimalist in itself

Comment: First of all, a "bug" is not simply something that doesn't work, and debugging is not just fixing it. Your code does the job, but it doesn't do it as expected (otherwise you wouldn't have asked about it), so a "bug" (no matter if practical or conceptual) *does* exist. And, no, while we, as *answerers*, may be curious by nature and eager to help out people, we are not here to investigate any code to look for its deepest issues until we find out the real problem. If you want help here, you *must* provide a MRE. Otherwise you'll just end up with vague and unhelpful answers (like the current one).

Comment: @musicamante thanks for your suggestions. I will wait for some time for answers. If don't get any answers, I will try and shorten the code in my post.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I solved the problem using Python's `asyncio` library (with the help of chatGPT). Here is the full working code:

```py
path_to_AI_model = #download from the link I provided in the question

import sys
import random
import asyncio
from enum import Enum
import functools
from PySide6.QtCore import QTimer, Qt, Signal, QRect, QThread, Slot
from PySide6.QtGui import QPainter, QColor, QPen, QFont, QBrush
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, QMainWindow, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QSizePolicy, QGridLayout, QLayout
import numpy as np
print(np.__version__)
import torch
print(torch.__version__)
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
torch.manual_seed(0)
from tqdm.notebook import trange
import random
import math

class CurrentPlayer(Enum):
    HUMAN = 1
    COMPUTER = -1

class gameStatus(Enum):
    HUMAN_LOST = -1
    DRAW = 0
    HUMAN_WON = 1
    IN_PROGRESS = 2

class Node:
    def __init__(self, game, args, state, parent=None, action_taken=None, prior=0, visit_count=0):
        self.game = game
        self.args = args
        self.state = state
        self.parent = parent
        self.action_taken = action_taken
        self.prior = prior
        
        self.children = []
        
        self.visit_count = visit_count
        self.value_sum = 0
        
    def is_fully_expanded(self):
        return len(self.children) > 0
    
    def select(self):
        best_child = None
        best_ucb = -np.inf
        
        for child in self.children:
            ucb = self.get_ucb(child)
            if ucb > best_ucb:
                best_child = child
                best_ucb = ucb
                
        return best_child
    
    def get_ucb(self, child):
        if child.visit_count == 0:
            q_value = 0
        else:
            q_value = 1 - ((child.value_sum / child.visit_count) + 1) / 2
        return q_value + self.args['C'] * (math.sqrt(self.visit_count) / (child.visit_count + 1)) * child.prior
    
    def expand(self, policy):
        for action, prob in enumerate(policy):
            if prob > 0:
                child_state = self.state.copy()
                child_state = self.game.get_next_state(child_state, action, 1)
                child_state = self.game.change_perspective(child_state, player=-1)

                child = Node(self.game, self.args, child_state, self, action, prob)
                self.children.append(child)
                
        return child
            
    def backpropagate(self, value):
        self.value_sum += value
        self.visit_count += 1
        
        value = self.game.get_opponent_value(value)
        if self.parent is not None:
            self.parent.backpropagate(value)  

class MCTS:
    def __init__(self, game, args, model):
        self.game = game
        self.args = args
        self.model = model
        
    @torch.no_grad()
    def search(self, state):
        root = Node(self.game, self.args, state, visit_count=1)
        
        policy, _ = self.model(
            torch.tensor(self.game.get_encoded_state(state), device=self.model.device).unsqueeze(0)
        )
        policy = torch.softmax(policy, axis=1).squeeze(0).cpu().numpy()
        policy = (1 - self.args['dirichlet_epsilon']) * policy + self.args['dirichlet_epsilon'] \
            * np.random.dirichlet([self.args['dirichlet_alpha']] * self.game.action_size)
        
        valid_moves = self.game.get_valid_moves(state)
        policy *= valid_moves
        policy /= np.sum(policy)
        root.expand(policy)
        
        for search in range(self.args['num_searches']):
            node = root
            
            while node.is_fully_expanded():
                node = node.select()
                
            value, is_terminal = self.game.get_value_and_terminated(node.state, node.action_taken)
            value = self.game.get_opponent_value(value)
            
            if not is_terminal:
                policy, value = self.model(
                    torch.tensor(self.game.get_encoded_state(node.state), device=self.model.device).unsqueeze(0)
                )
                policy = torch.softmax(policy, axis=1).squeeze(0).cpu().numpy()
                valid_moves = self.game.get_valid_moves(node.state)
                policy *= valid_moves
                policy /= np.sum(policy)
                
                value = value.item()
                
                node.expand(policy)
                
            node.backpropagate(value)    
            
            
        action_probs = np.zeros(self.game.action_size)
        for child in root.children:
            action_probs[child.action_taken] = child.visit_count
        action_probs /= np.sum(action_probs)
        return action_probs
    
class ResBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_hidden):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(num_hidden, num_hidden, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(num_hidden)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(num_hidden, num_hidden, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(num_hidden)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        residual = x
        x = F.relu(self.bn1(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.bn2(self.conv2(x))
        x += residual
        x = F.relu(x)
        return x
    
class ResNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, game, num_resBlocks, num_hidden, device):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.device = device
        self.startBlock = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(3, num_hidden, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(num_hidden),
            nn.ReLU()
        )
        
        self.backBone = nn.ModuleList(
            [ResBlock(num_hidden) for i in range(num_resBlocks)]
        )
        
        self.policyHead = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(num_hidden, 32, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Flatten(),
            nn.Linear(32 * game.row_count * game.column_count, game.action_size)
        )
        
        self.valueHead = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(num_hidden, 3, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(3),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Flatten(),
            nn.Linear(3 * game.row_count * game.column_count, 1),
            nn.Tanh()
        )
        
        self.to(device)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.startBlock(x)
        for resBlock in self.backBone:
            x = resBlock(x)
        policy = self.policyHead(x)
        value = self.valueHead(x)
        return policy, value
    
class ConnectFour:
    def __init__(self):
        self.row_count = 6
        self.column_count = 7
        self.action_size = self.column_count
        self.in_a_row = 4
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return "ConnectFour"
        
    def get_initial_state(self):
        return np.zeros((self.row_count, self.column_count))
    
    def get_next_state(self, state, action, player):
        row = np.max(np.where(state[:, action] == 0))
        state[row, action] = player
        return state
    
    def get_valid_moves(self, state):
        return (state[0] == 0).astype(np.uint8)
    
    def check_win(self, state, action):
        if action == None:
            return False
        
        row = np.min(np.where(state[:, action] != 0))
        column = action
        player = state[row][column]

        def count(offset_row, offset_column):
            for i in range(1, self.in_a_row):
                r = row + offset_row * i
                c = action + offset_column * i
                if (
                    r < 0 
                    or r >= self.row_count
                    or c < 0 
                    or c >= self.column_count
                    or state[r][c] != player
                ):
                    return i - 1
            return self.in_a_row - 1

        return (
            count(1, 0) >= self.in_a_row - 1 # vertical
            or (count(0, 1) + count(0, -1)) >= self.in_a_row - 1 # horizontal
            or (count(1, 1) + count(-1, -1)) >= self.in_a_row - 1 # top left diagonal
            or (count(1, -1) + count(-1, 1)) >= self.in_a_row - 1 # top right diagonal
        )
    
    def get_value_and_terminated(self, state, action):
        if self.check_win(state, action):
            return 1, True
        if np.sum(self.get_valid_moves(state)) == 0:
            return 0, True
        return 0, False
    
    def get_opponent(self, player):
        return -player
    
    def get_opponent_value(self, value):
        return -value
    
    def change_perspective(self, state, player):
        return state * player
    
    def get_encoded_state(self, state):
        encoded_state = np.stack(
            (state == -1, state == 0, state == 1)
        ).astype(np.float32)
        
        return encoded_state
    
class AlphaZeroWorker(QThread):
    dataToMain = Signal(dict)

    def __init__(self, mainWindow):
        super().__init__()
        self.mainWindow = mainWindow
        self.device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
        self.game = ConnectFour()
        self.args = {
            'C': 2,
            'num_searches': 100,
            'dirichlet_epsilon': 0.,
            'dirichlet_alpha': 0.3
        }
        self.model = ResNet(self.game, 9, 128, self.device)
        self.model.load_state_dict(torch.load(path_to_AI_model, map_location=self.device))
        self.model.eval()
        self.mcts = MCTS(self.game, self.args, self.model)

    def run(self):
        asyncio.run(self.workerThread())
    
    async def computeAIMove(self, moves, player, action):
        neutral_state = self.game.change_perspective(moves, player)
        mcts_probs = self.mcts.search(neutral_state)
        action = np.argmax(mcts_probs)
        moves = self.game.get_next_state(moves, action, player)
        val, is_terminal = self.game.get_value_and_terminated(moves, action)
        return_dict = {"moves": moves, "val": val, "is_terminal": is_terminal}
        return return_dict
    
    async def workerThread(self):
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            if self.mainWindow.status == gameStatus.IN_PROGRESS and self.mainWindow.player == CurrentPlayer.COMPUTER:
                result = await self.computeAIMove(
                self.mainWindow.board.moves,
                self.mainWindow.player.value,
                self.mainWindow.playerAction
            )
                self.dataToMain.emit(result)
                
class TimerWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent, cellWidth):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent().buttonClickedSignal.connect(self.resetTimer)
        self.parent().timerResetSignal.connect(self.resetTimer)
        self.parent().gameOverSignal.connect(self.resetTimer)
        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.cellWidth = cellWidth
        self.time_elapsed = 0
        self.max_time = 20000
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updateTimer)
        self.timer.start(20)

    def updateTimer(self):
        self.time_elapsed += 20
        if self.time_elapsed >= self.max_time:
            self.timer.stop()
            self.parent().status = gameStatus.HUMAN_LOST
            self.parent().gameOverSignal.emit()
            self.parent().update()
        self.update()
    
    def resetTimer(self):
        self.time_elapsed = 0
        if self.parent().status != gameStatus.IN_PROGRESS:
            self.timer.stop()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter(self)
        if not qp.isActive():
            qp.begin(self)
        qp.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        qp.fillRect(self.rect(), QBrush(QColor(20, 20, 20)))
        rect = self.rect()
        w = min(rect.width(), rect.height()) - self.cellWidth
        rect = QRect(self.cellWidth/2, self.cellWidth/2, w, w)
        start_angle = 90 * 16 
        span_angle = abs(int((self.max_time - self.time_elapsed) / self.max_time * 360 * 16))
        pen = QPen()
        pen.setColor(QColor(255, 255, 255))
        pen.setWidth(10)
        qp.setPen(pen)
        qp.drawEllipse(rect)
        if self.parent().player == CurrentPlayer.COMPUTER:
            pen.setColor(QColor(50, 255, 0))
        else:
            pen.setColor(QColor(50, 0, 255))
        pen.setWidth(11)
        qp.setPen(pen)
        qp.drawArc(rect, start_angle, span_angle)
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        qp.setFont(font)
        time_left_in_seconds = int(abs(self.max_time - self.time_elapsed)/1000)
        qp.drawText(rect, Qt.AlignCenter, f"Time Left:\n{time_left_in_seconds} seconds")
        qp.end()
        
class gameInfoWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.statusMessageDict = {
            -1: "Game Over\nYou Lost",
            0: "Game Over\nDraw",
            1: "Game Over\nYou Won!",
            2: "Game in Progress",
        }

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter(self)
        if not qp.isActive():
            qp.begin(self)
        pen = QPen()
        font = QFont()
        pen.setColor(QColor(255, 255, 255))
        font.setPointSize(15)
        qp.setPen(pen)
        qp.setFont(font)
        message = self.statusMessageDict.get(self.parent().status.value, "Unknown Status")
        qp.drawText(self.rect(), Qt.AlignCenter, message)
        self.show()
        qp.end()

class Connect4Board(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent, cellWidth):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.cellWidth = cellWidth
        self.buttons = []
        self.button_i_status = [True for _ in range(7)]
        self.moves = np.array([[0 for _ in range(7)] for _ in range(6)])
        self.parent().gameOverSignal.connect(self.disableButtons)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(self.rect())
        self.createButtons()
        self.show()

    def createButtons(self):
        font = QFont("Arial", 15) 
        for column in range(7):
            self.buttons.append(QPushButton(f"{column+1}", self))
            self.buttons[column].setFont(font)
            self.buttons[column].setGeometry((column+0.75)*self.cellWidth, 6.75*self.cellWidth, self.cellWidth/2, self.cellWidth/2)
            self.buttons[column].clicked.connect(functools.partial(self.buttonClicked, column))

    def disableButtons(self):
        for column in range(0, 7):
            self.buttons[column].setEnabled(False)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter(self)
        if not qp.isActive():
            qp.begin(self)
        qp.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.drawBackground(qp)
        self.drawGrid(qp)
        self.drawMoves(qp)
        qp.end()

    def drawBackground(self, qp):
        qp.fillRect(self.rect(), QBrush(QColor(20, 20, 20)))
        
    def drawGrid(self, qp):
        qp.setPen(Qt.white)
        qp.setBrush(Qt.white)
        for i in range(0, 7):
           qp.drawLine(self.cellWidth/2, (i+0.5)*self.cellWidth, 7.5*self.cellWidth, (i+0.5)*self.cellWidth)
        for i in range(0, 8):
           qp.drawLine((i+0.5)*self.cellWidth, self.cellWidth/2, (i+0.5)*self.cellWidth, 6.5*self.cellWidth)

    def drawMoves(self, qp):
        for i in range(0, 6):
            for j in range(0, 7):
                if self.moves[i][j]:
                    if self.moves[i][j] == CurrentPlayer.COMPUTER.value:
                        qp.setPen(QColor(50, 255, 0))
                        qp.setBrush(QColor(50, 255, 0))
                    else:
                        qp.setPen(QColor(50, 0, 255))
                        qp.setBrush(QColor(50, 0, 255))
                    qp.drawEllipse((j+0.6)*self.cellWidth, (i+0.6)*self.cellWidth, 0.8*self.cellWidth, 0.8*self.cellWidth)
            
    def buttonClicked(self, column):
        self.playerAction = column
        if self.moves[0][column] == 0:
            for row in range(-1, -7, -1):
                if self.moves[row][column] == 0:
                    self.moves[row][column] = self.parent().player.value
                    break
            self.parent().repaint()
            for column in range(7):
                self.buttons[column].setEnabled(False)
            self.parent().buttonClickedSignal.emit()
            self.parent().switchPlayer()
        else:
            self.button_i_status[column] = False

    def computerMove(self, data):
        self.moves = data["moves"]
        val = data["val"]
        is_terminal = data["is_terminal"]
        if is_terminal:
            print(self.moves)
            if val == 1:
                print(self.parent().player, "won")
                if self.parent().player.value == 1:
                    self.parent().status = self.parent().status.HUMAN_WON
                elif self.parent().player.value == -1:
                    self.parent().status = self.parent().status.HUMAN_LOST
            else:
                self.parent().status = gameStatus.DRAW
                print("draw")
            self.parent().gameOverSignal.emit()
            self.parent().update()
        else:
            self.parent().update()
            self.parent().switchPlayer()
            self.parent().timerResetSignal.emit()
            for column in range(7):
                if self.button_i_status[column]:
                    self.buttons[column].setEnabled(True)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    buttonClickedSignal = Signal()
    timerResetSignal = Signal()
    gameOverSignal = Signal()
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.player = CurrentPlayer.HUMAN
        self.status = gameStatus.IN_PROGRESS
        self.cellWidth = 80
        self.playerAction = 0
        self.alphazero = AlphaZeroWorker(self)
        self.alphazero.start()
        self.board = Connect4Board(self, self.cellWidth)
        self.timer = TimerWidget(self, self.cellWidth)
        self.gameInfo = gameInfoWidget(self)
        self.alphazero.dataToMain.connect(self.board.computerMove)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Connect Four")
        self.setFixedSize(10.5*self.cellWidth, 7.5*self.cellWidth)

        self.board.setGeometry(0, 0, 7.5*self.cellWidth, 7.5*self.cellWidth)
        self.timer.setGeometry(7.5*self.cellWidth, 0, 3*self.cellWidth, 3*self.cellWidth)
        self.gameInfo.setGeometry(7.5*self.cellWidth, 3.5*self.cellWidth, 3*self.cellWidth, 5*self.cellWidth)

        self.board.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.timer.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gameInfo.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)

        self.board.setMinimumSize(7.5*self.cellWidth, 7.5*self.cellWidth)
        self.timer.setMinimumSize(3*self.cellWidth, 3*self.cellWidth)
        self.gameInfo.setMinimumSize(3*self.cellWidth, 5*self.cellWidth)

        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter(self)
        if not qp.isActive():
            qp.begin(self)
        qp.fillRect(self.rect(), QBrush(QColor(20, 20, 20)))
        qp.end()

    def switchPlayer(self):
        if self.player == CurrentPlayer.COMPUTER:
            self.player = CurrentPlayer.HUMAN
        else:
            self.player = CurrentPlayer.COMPUTER

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if QApplication.instance():
        app = QApplication.instance()
    else:
        app = QApplication([])
    player = CurrentPlayer.HUMAN
    gameMainWindow = MainWindow()
    app.exec()
    def on_app_exit():
        gameMainWindow.alphazero.stop()
        app.quit()
        del app
    app.aboutToQuit.connect(on_app_exit)
```